# Include SQL in XML

Tags: android, sql, xml

Is it possible to include an SQL query inside an XML into `raw/` directory? For example:

```
<query name ="mainQuery">SELECT e.*, et.name as name FROM employee e, employee_type et where e.type = et._id and et._id < et._id</query>
```

or

```
<query name ="mainQuery" value="SELECT e.*, et.name as name FROM employee e, employee_type et where e.type = et._id and et._id < et._id" />
```

Both these give errors on XML structure. One workaround is using `&lt;` and friends, but this really makes no sense as SQL syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you noticed you need to use `&lt:` for `<` in XML since `<` is a reserved character. But claiming that this makes "no sense", is equivalent to refusing to use strings in Java because you must use `\"` for a `"`...

Comment: Well, I said "makes no sense **as SQL syntax**". So yes, it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA). Example:

```
<query name ="mainQuery"><![CDATA[SELECT e.*, et.name as name FROM employee e, employee_type et where e.type = et._id and et._id < et._id]]></query>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into putting the query in a comment and then reading the comment from within your activity?

See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11178/Writing-SQL-queries-in-XML-A-support-intensive-app

Comment: Thanks; I saw that post but putting the most important thing on a comment... Looks more like a hack than a real solution.